# OpenZeppelin MintableToken error only on private network

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, openzeppelin

I started a new private network by geth command.

```
geth --networkid "198"  --nodiscover --datadir "~/test-geth" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcvhosts "*" --rpcapi web3,eth,personal,miner,net,txpool,debug --unlock 0,1 --password /home/user/.gethpasswd --mine --minerthreads 1 --targetgaslimit 6721975 --gasprice "100000"
```

And deployed my token to this network. "truffle compile" & "truffle migrate" succeeded.
But sendTransaction fails everytime…

I debugged with truffle debugger. Here is the result of “sendTransaction”.

```
MintedCrowdsale.sol:

24:   {
25:     // Potentially dangerous assumption about the type of the token.
26:     require(MintableToken(address(token)).mint(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

debug(development:0xb76ce508...)> i

Transaction halted with a RUNTIME ERROR.

This is likely due to an intentional halting expression, like assert(), require() or revert(). It can also be due to out-of-gas exceptions. Please inspect your transaction parameters and contract code to determine the meaning of this error.
```

I thought this error may be occurred by failure of "transferOwnership", but truffle debugger says "transferOwnership" succeeded.

And, strangely, no error occurs when using ganache-cli or Ropsten test net…

I get errors only on private network established by geth command.

Please tell me if anyone has advice on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got a solution.

My genesis block setting was wrong.

This setting works fine for me.

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 198,
    "HomesteadBlock":      0,
    "DAOForkBlock": 0,
    "DAOForkSupport":      true,
    "EIP150Block":         0,
    "EIP155Block":         0,
    "EIP158Block":         0,
    "ByzantiumBlock":      0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x4000",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

And, in migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {


    const wallet = accounts[0];
```

causes gaslimit error.

```
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {


    const wallet = "<your address>";
```

is OK.